# "Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://..." after running adb reverse command

Tags: android, flutter, dart, adb, flutter-debug

I have a flutter app that I debug on real device, and it runs fine in the debug mode.

I got to a point when I created a backend server that runs in a `localhost:8080` only machine, so in order to make it accessible from my real phone device also, I ran:

```
adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

and it worked exactly as I expected where the app was running.

But, after this, if I re-rerun the app again in the real device ( unplug and plug again the USB in the machine ), it got to the point of showing the `√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.` and this error got thrown and it terminate/close the debug process of the app :

```
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:61410/DHX5GEb2kn4=/
```

[image: Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:61410/DHX5GEb2kn4=/]

I did try to kill the adb.exe command with:

```
adb kill-server
```

supposing that this will undo the `adb reverse` command but the same error gets thrown

well, I found a painful fix, which is restarting the device, but this takes much time and is painful.

I want to know what should I turn on/off while debugging my flutter app

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fic the issue, and get my app debugging properly again.

**What I did wrong ?**

When I needed the `adb`, I thought it's not installed on my laptop since when I runned `adb` command in command line tool (cmd), it tells me that it's not recognized, so the smart me did downloaded the android platforms-tools separatly from [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)
, and I runned the :

```
adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

from it's folder, which runned, and I thought I solved the issue, but what I just learned is that the Dart VM server uses an internal installed another `adb.exe` which have a different version (39) that what I run the command with (41).

so when I re-debug the flutter project, the error happens.

**How did I fix it?**

1. I did simply searched for the internal `adb.exe`, you can find in the `Android` folder, `...\Android\SDK\platforms\tools\adb.exe`.
2. I Paste the new `adb.exe` with the height version inside the folder.
3. Run the command from that folder

For 3., you can set the path of that folder in the `PATH` in environment variables, so you can run the `adb` commands from anywhere.